# What is a simple, small, yet nice RSI watcher for Windows?

Tags: windows, software-rec, ergonomics

I would like to know a tool to enforce regular breaks from typing to avoid wrist pain.

I have a preference for simplicity, unobtrusiveness (at least until break time comes), a small resource footprint, and, if possible, "non-ugliness".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Workrave](http://www.workrave.org/welcome/). Cross-platform, simple, wonderful.

Comment: 26 seconds! Sheesh :P

Comment: I had to type fast before it told me it was time for a break. ;)

Comment: Workrave is quite good. Especially the unobtrusive part. It literally gets "out of your way". Nice.

Answer (score 3):

I found WorkRave increased my stress 10 times and I just ignored all it's breaks in the end.

**[Eyes Relax](http://themech.net/eyesrelax/)** is far better and less annoying than Workrave. You can set a picture, slideshows, custom noises etc.

**[Eye defender](http://www.eterlab.com/eyedefender/)** is another good one but has less options.

The best system is to use the very simple and effective **[Pomodoro time management technique](http://www.pomodorotechnique.com/)** as it teaches the true productivity benefits for working in 25 min block with 5 min breaks (trust me it will change your work life)

Once you're using that method you can use [this windows gadget](http://sharovatov.wordpress.com/2009/12/03/pomodoro-windows-7-gadget/) to make sure you don't spend to long at your pc or too long far away ;) There is one for mac i'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

Well, its not an RSI watcher, but when Im seeing a movie or some tv show I strengthen my wrists by using a [powerball](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r5cM84qSj5o).

It can be dangerous if you have a curious dog with a tongue =)

Answer (score 0):

A colleague of mine has a roster in his Outlook Calender that alerts him every half hour or so, he just moves it along days so he can reuse it. Rather clean and simple, though not as elegant as an app designed for workbreaks