# A free program to remind you to take breaks

Tags: windows, software-rec, ergonomics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a simple, small, yet nice RSI watcher for Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/6033/what-is-a-simple-small-yet-nice-rsi-watcher-for-windows)

I'm looking for a free program that pops up every half an hour and reminds you to take a few minutes off and stretch yourself. I've found [Stretch Break](http://www.paratec.com/), which costs money. Any alternatives?

Comment: i swear i've seen this asked before, but my searches aren't finding anything.  :-/

Comment: Actually, yes.  Here: http://superuser.com/questions/6033/what-is-a-simple-small-yet-nice-rsi-watcher-for-windows  I just searched here for "Workrave".

Comment: Stratchly might be a good choice as well .. 
https://github.com/hovancik/stretchly/releases

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out [Workrave](http://workrave.org/welcome/).

- Free?  Check.
- Has sheep?  Check.

> Workrave is a program that assists in
>   the recovery and prevention of
>   Repetitive Strain Injury (RSI). The
>   program frequently alerts you to take
>   micro-pauses, rest breaks and
>   restricts you to your daily limit.
>   Please refer to the feature comparison
>   for a complete list of features, and
>   how the program performs with respect
>   to other programs on the market. The
>   program runs on GNU/Linux and
>   Microsoft Windows.

[image: Workrave rest break]

And if that's not enough, [here's a comparison](http://www.qompr.com/charts/58;rsi-prevention-tools/) of many RSI-prevention utilities (albeit, authored by Workrave).

Comment: you know why scotsmen wear kilts, dontcha?

Answer (score 5):

For Windows?  Windows Task Scheduler can run any program you like, so pick something (a music player, for example, or a JPG viewer showing a JPG that says "Take a break!") and schedule it to start whenever you want to take breaks.

For Linux, a *cron* or *at* script can do the same thing.

All free with your operating system of choice.

[Here](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/create-a-task-to-display-a-popup-message-in-window.html) are the steps to Display a Pop-Up Message in Windows

Comment: i' ve done this at work with rundll32 and MessageBox .. pretty hacky :)

Comment: i used *at* + *mpg321* + a textfile playlist of MP3s for a wake-up alarm in college.

Answer (score 1):

**[Reflexion](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Others/Home-Education/Reflexion.shtml)** makes sure you take a break.

> Often when doing programming one
>   forgets the time and the necessity to
>   take a break a regular intervals.
>   Reflexion will gently tell you it's
>   time for this. Stretch your legs and
>   get a coffee. While nipping on your
>   drink ponder upon the way you are
>   tackling the problem. Many times you
>   find a better and easier way saving
>   you time and effort.
>
> Many authority's recommend a small
>   pause (1 or 2 minutes) per hour of
>   computer work. Reflexion is a tinny
>   application that prompts you kindly
>   when it is time for a pause.
>
> Reflexion will run in the windows
>   notification area. You can set the
>   start and stop time and the number of
>   pauses you like. A list is dynamically
>   updated and showing all the pause
>   occurences. Optionaly one can play a
>   sound (wav), mp3 or wma file to
>   prelude the pause.

Here are some key features of "Reflexion":

- Start-End Time
- Number of Reflexions
- Reflexion Times
- Increment selectable
- Users can choose what sound to play when it's time for a break.
  · Has the feature to run in background.

*Reflexion is freeware.*

**[My Rest Break](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Enhancements/Clocks-Time-Management/My-Rest-Break.shtml)** is a software that reminds you to take regular breaks while using the computer. Taking regular breaks can reduce the risk of unhealthy side effects due to prolonged computer use. In fact, according to health experts one should take short breaks after 20 to 30 minutes while working on computer. Prolonged computer use can lead to several ill effects.

[image]

> One can develop deep-vein thrombosis (DVT) from working too long at a computer without taking rest breaks. DVT can be a serious, life threatening medical emergency. Other potential adverse health conditions could include repetitive strain injury (RSI) and computer vision syndrome (CVS).

*My Rest Break is freeware.*

Comment: Ummm... are DVT and CVS real?

Comment: @Nathaniel - Hell, if i know. but it sounds cool, so i thought: why not include this quote in my answer :)

Comment: CVS is real.  i prefer SVN or GIT tho.  (deep-vein thrombosis is real, tho i've never heard it called DVT:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_vein_thrombosis ... and the other CVS is a form of eye-strain, usually temporary: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_vision_syndrome )

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Pomodoro technique. See http://www.pomodorotechnique.com/ for more information.

There's a number of timers out there that implement pomodoro.  A quick Google turned up:

www.focusboosterapp.com/ (AIR app, runs on Windows, Mac, Linux)
www.designinginteractive.com/reviews/my-favorite-pomodoro-timers/

Answer (score 0):

I use Outlook while at work for this very thing.  I just setup recurring appointments every hour to remind me to stand up and drink some water.