# Windows equivalent for Time Out?

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a simple, small, yet nice RSI watcher for Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/6033/what-is-a-simple-small-yet-nice-rsi-watcher-for-windows)

I'm looking for an equivalent for Dejal's Time out application ([Dejal](http://www.dejal.com/timeout/)). Any suggestion is appreciated.

**Update:** Basically, I need a break reminder (Repetitive Strain Injury prevention) tool for Windows.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try [WorkRave](http://www.workrave.org/):

> Workrave is a program that assists in the recovery and prevention of Repetitive Strain Injury (RSI). The program frequently alerts you to take micro-pauses, rest breaks and restricts you to your daily limit. Please refer to the feature comparison for a complete list of features, and how the program performs with respect to other programs on the market. The program runs on GNU/Linux and Microsoft Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like a regular time reminder. There's tons of them out there.

Here's just a few:

http://www.024h.com/time-reminder-program.html

http://www.timeleft.info/

http://www.xreminder.com/

http://www.freedownloadscenter.com/free/807737/

Comment: The last link provides multiple free source programs.

Comment: not exactly what i'm looking for

Comment: Well, could you elaborate so I can help you out?

Comment: The Time Out app from Dejal - http://dejal.com/timeout/ - gently stops you from what you are doing by taking over the desktop. check out the screenshots on their web site. That's what I need, not just a reminder. Thanks anyway.